# My firebase data disappears after some time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not great with firebase but I managed to successfully integrate my database with my code. It successfully saves the data onto the real time database however I noticed that after some time the data just disappears, not sure why this is happening. Is there a reason why the database wouldn't store the data permanently?

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const name = document.querySelector('#name').value
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value
    const question = document.querySelector('#question').value

    const id = name + ' '+ email.slice(0,2)
    


    firebase.database().ref('table1/'+id).set({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      text:question,
    })
    
    success()
    setOpen(false);
    

  };
```

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Comment: Sure! Updated it now

Comment: You're either overwriting your data or, you are attempting to write a nil value (accidentally) and when that happens, the node disappears. In The Realtime Database, a node cannot existing without a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime Database is in essence a large JSON object and writing data at the wrong location can remove data from your database.

The first concern is **how** you are writing data to the database.

With your current code, you are ignoring all error messages that you get when writing to the database. This could be one of the causes for missing data.

Handling errors using [Promise chaining](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises/):

```
/* ... */

firebase.database().ref('table1/'+id).set({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  text:question,
})
.then(
  () => {
    // data set successfully
    success();
    setOpen(false);
  },
  (err) => {
    // something went wrong
    // update UI with error info (missing data, needs login, etc)
    console.error(err);
  }
);
```

or the newer [`async`/`await` syntax](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions):

```
try {
  /* ... */

  await firebase.database().ref('table1/'+id).set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    text:question,
  })

  // if here, data was set successfully
  success();
  setOpen(false);
} catch (error) {
  // if here, something went wrong
  // update UI with error info (missing data, needs login, etc)
  console.error(error);
}
```

Another concern is **where** you are writing data to the database.

Imagine the following data structure:

```json
{
  table1: {
    pushId1: { /* ... */ },
    pushId2: { /* ... */ },
    pushId3: { /* ... */ },
    pushId4: { /* ... */ }
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

For conciseness, I will omit the error-handling as shown above. You should always make sure you are handling errors & promises properly.

If you push data to `table1`, it gets added inside of `table1`.

```
firebase.database().ref('table1').push({ /* ... */ });  // creates /table1/pushId5
```

If you set data to `table1/<id>`, it gets added inside of `table1` as the child `<id>`.

```
firebase.database().ref('table1/' + id).set({ /* ... */ }); // creates/overwrites /table1/<id>
// or
firebase.database().ref('table1').child(id).set({ /* ... */ }); // creates/overwrites /table1/<id>
```

If you instead set the data to `table1`, it gets **replaces all data** inside of `table1`.

```
firebase.database().ref('table1').set({ /* ... */ }); // creates/overwrites /table1
```

This also causes the same result:

```
firebase.database().ref('table1/').set({ /* ... */ }); // creates/overwrites /table1
```

With the code you have posted, there doesn't appear to be any input validation. This could lead to a case where `id = ' '`. While a value of `' '` isn't an issue on it's own, if you didn't have that space there, like `id = name + email.slice(0,2)`, this means `id` could be `''`. When this is the case, your `set()` operation would have deleted all the values in `table1` and replaced it with the `{ name, email, question }` object. In addition, if you have another function along the lines of "delete my data" that has the wrong ID format, you could inadvertently delete all of your data with such a typo.